# Atom editor, atom-beautify plugin error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setScrollTop' of null

Tags: javascript, json, atom-editor

I have been using Atom's atom-beautify plugin for quite some time now, but all of a sudden since yesterday, whenever I try to beautify/save my C code I got the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setScrollTop' of null
```

screenshot below:

[image]

and sometimes I get a different error:

[image]

the issue has been reported in the github repository multiple times (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/1339)) with no proper solutions so far. That's why I'm asking for help here instead! I did some research and it seems it is a Javascript/JSON issue hence the tags. Sorry if they are not relevant, as a C programer I don't know that much about JavaScript and JSON.

I'm using atom editor on my mac OS X elcappitan but others have also reported the same issue on windows and linux. I would appreciate if you could help me understand why this happens and how I can fix this.

Comment: I was using that plugin many times and didn't met with that error yet. Just to make sure - did you try to reinstall the plugin? Or even whole Atom?

Comment: I'm hesitant to reinstall the whole atom again because I have to reinstall a lot of plugins again (just if atom had the feature to save your plugins/settings!), but I will reinstall the plugin now and will report here again.

Comment: I did reinstall the plugin and I can see the error anymore. But I'm not sure that it will not come back again because before it was also random somehow!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answers:

- use a different package for now;
- and unless you're fluent in JavaScript/CoffeeScript, I wouldn't change any of the package contents.

Explanations:

JSON is a straight-forward **key:value** pairing system, such as `{"name":"Donald Duck"}`.

That error is in JavaScript (obviously), because Atom uses CoffeeScript, JavaScript, CSS and HTML to make their editor--and since you're using a plugin, I'm pretty sure the plugin maker set one of the values to an unintentional `null` when trying to find an HTML element that it relies on.

So--the plugin is looking for an HTML element (via CoffeeScript [JavaScript]) that doesn't exist, but can be fixed manually (if you're fluent in Coffee).

This issue is also in Brackets, and the only solution was to use an entirely different package.

Comment: I just added a new picture to the question. is there any chance that you can identify that "HTML element" and help me fix it manually? it is a very important plugin for me and i want to use it.

Comment: For the first picture: Yes, the second one: no.

Comment: The file isn't minified, so it would be easy to look at; but I would need time to read the code to see where they were going with the plugin.

Comment: what do you mean by "first yes but second no"? are these do different bugs?

Comment: Yes, they are two different bugs.

Comment: but they happen together and appeared at the same time! any chance that they are related?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `view?.setScrollTop` can't handle and unknown value, I'll submit a pull request.

These are the lines causing the problem:

```
setScrollTop = (editor, value) ->
  view = atom.views.getView(editor)
  view ?.setScrollTop value
```

This is a **possible** solution:

```
setScrollTop = (editor, value) ->
  view = atom.views.getView(editor)
  view ?.setScrollTop value ?0
```